# Unclear legend with shape and linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot where I differentiate two classes of data. In addition to colour*, I want to use shape for the points and linetype for the smooths so that the plot is printer etc friendly.

The plot works fine, but the legend is difficult - the point almost perfectly fills the gap in the dashed line.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(44)
data_frame(x = rep(1:10, 2), y = rnorm(20), z = gl(n = 2, k = 10)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z, shape = z, linetype = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

[image]

I know I could make two legends, but that seems redundant. Is it possible to move the position of the shape to the end of the line in the legend? I tried using a dotted line but that didn't help much.

(*In my actual code, I am using scale_colour_brewer)

Comment: One option is to vary the sizes of the traces themselves, and of the legend to make things more clear.  E.g. `geom_smooth(se = FALSE, size=0.5) + theme(legend.key.width = unit(1, 'cm'))`. Another way would be to forgo the automatic legend and draw your own using geom_line, geom_point, and geom_text

Comment: @dww thanks `legend.key.width` does pretty much what I needed